# Is it possible to make a link that would open an app if tapped on an iPhone and a website if on a desktop?

Tags: html, ios, hyperlink, url-scheme

I am wondering if it is possible to make a link that if tapped on (say in iOS Mail), would open up a specific app (I know that part is possible), AND if the very same link were opened up on a regular computer say in Gmail, it would function as a regular web link.

So essentially, two different links in one, depending on the platform you are on.

Where would I start to get something like this going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did it this morning.  You need to have your link in the email go to your website.  Then on your website check the user-agent and redirect to the app if the user-agent is for iOS and if it is not iOS show the regular web page.

Comment: I knew I had seen it done before, thanks for sharing the implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because you don't have control on which device email is shown. 
Best approach would be to code (css/html) responsive email template and hide first link(for pc) if screen size is < 600px etc.

More on responsive emails:
http://zurb.com/article/1144/a-tutorial-on-responsive-email-templates